# Poisson-gamma posterior mean expectation

Tags: probability, bayesian, empirical-bayes

Let's have a gamma prior $\lambda\sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a,b)$ (mean: $\frac{a}{b}$)

With Poisson data $Y\mid \lambda\sim \operatorname{Pois}(N\lambda)$ (mean: $N\lambda$)

The posterior is $\lambda\mid Y\sim \operatorname{Gamma}(a+Y,b+N)$

The posterior mean is $E(\lambda\mid Y)=\frac{Y+a}{N+b}$.

What is its expectation? $E(E(\lambda\mid Y))=\frac{\tfrac{a}{b}+a}{N+b}$? How is this estimator called?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you doing some form of MAP? Would be great if you can add more context to your question.

Comment: I would be interested in, when I repeatedly sample from a Poisson, given samples from a gamma distribution, what will be the mean of this samples. In the case of a MAP, I would be thinking that maybe the mode $\frac{a-1}{b}$ would be used.

Comment: I posted also on cross-validated, since it seems that there is a better scientific basis for this type of problem. Hope that's fine (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/417505/poisson-gamma-posterior-mean-expectation)